# dict comprehension failure - not enough values to unpack

Tags: python, dictionary, iterable-unpacking

I want to create a dict from a list of strings:

```
print(l)
print(l[0])                            # 1st string in list
print(l[0].split(',',1))
print(len(l[0].split(',',1)))
d = {int(k):v for k,v in l[0].split(',',1)}

['0,[7,2,5,7]', '1,[7,18,6,2]']
0,[7,2,5,7]
['0', '[7,2,5,7]']
2
```

However, I get `d = {int(k):v for k,v in l[0].split(',',1)}     ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`

I can't understand why, as `l[0].split(',',1)` returns 2 values, as can be seen from my previous checks (`print(len(l[0].split(',',1)))` returns 2)

*My desired output:*

```
d = {0 : [7,2,5,7]}
```

Comment: I edited it into the question, but how does it matter? `l[0]` should give complete information, no?

Comment: So you want to turn the first element of `l` into a dict with a single key/value pair? That seems odd. What's the point of a dict with only a single key inside of it? It would make more sense to turn the whole list `l` into a dict, no?

Comment: The `len` return two and it returns two values, seems like it should be.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I'm testing it for the 1st element. When I'll fix this issue, I'll expand it for the entire list (`l` can be much bigger)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns two values but the loop expects a list of two values.

You have this: `[x, y]`

But the code expects this: `[[x, y]]`

You could do:

```
from itertools import repeat
items = map(str.split, l, repeat(','), repeat(1))
d = {int(k):v for k,v in items}
```

Note that you'll get all the data and not just one item.

You may want to parse the list using [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) because currently its a string:

```
import ast
from itertools import repeat
items = map(str.split, l, repeat(','), repeat(1))
d = {int(k):ast.literal_eval(v) for k,v in items}
```

Comment: Surely `(s.split(',', 1) for s in l)` would've been more readable than this weird `map(str.split, l, repeat(','), repeat(1))` construct?

Comment: @Aran-Fey Not for *me*. But you may use what you choose. I don't like a lot of syntax that gets out of hand quickly. Maybe it isn't that weird and you're just no used to it? Anyway, I'd prefer to use `partial` if not the `map` - but honestly its very readable to me (`repeat` in `map` is just a constant binding on a parameter).